# Problem with adding Views - they cannot be saved

Tags: views

I have problem with creating new views (or clone old ones). All process is doing well, I choose my filtres etc; but when I'm trying to save it's an error - and they don't show in the views list (even if it's said that it "has been saved"). I've already tried several times but it doesn't work. I dont know why - before I didn't have this problem...[image: system communictate]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running update.php? Or try clearing the Drupal cache which you can do quickly with drush using drush cc all.

I find this is always a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

It's stated in the error message. You're missing the `core` column in the `views_view` table. If this is a new install, then you can disable, uninstall and after wards re-enable the views module.

Otherwhise execute this code in SQL (PHPMyAdmin or whatever database GUI you use):

```
ALTER TABLE `views_view` ADD `core` int(11) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Stores the drupal core version of the view.';
UPDATE `views_view` SET core = 6;
```

Assuming an SQL dialect, e.g. MySQL, and Drupal 6.